# How to invoke native android maps app from a normal link <a>?

Tags: android, html, maps

I want to invoke the native device maps app to show some directions between the current position of a user and another location.

In iOS 6 it's working this way:

`<a href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=lon,lat&saddr=lon,lat"></a>`

But how is this working on other platforms e.g. on android?

Answer (score 2):

In Android, you can use a `geo:` url to achieve this.
Have a look at the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) for the parameters.

Basically it goes

```
<a href="geo:lat,lon">My place</a>
```

It may be that this fires the application selector on the user's device, as the user may have installed more than "maps" kind of app.